# Convert gdata feed to xml - Youtube Playlist to ANdroid Listview

Tags: android, youtube

I am following [this code](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/) to create a custom list view.

It uses [an XML file](http://api.androidhive.info/music/music.xml) to parse objects and show them in `Listview`

I was wondering can I use the same example to show Videos Titles and Duration of a Youtube Playlist.

I have gone though Youtube API and GDATA but I can't find out how to get raw xml link which I can use with above example code

Any help guys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heres a class I've used in one of my previous projects. This puts the first video as the "main" one, displays the time and title, and then adds all the rest of the videos to a layout.

```
public class Videos extends Activity {
    ImageView mainThumb;
    TextView mainTitle;
    TextView mainTime;
    LinearLayout videos;
    ArrayList<String> links;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.videos);

        new ParseVideoDataTask().execute();
        mainThumb = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mainThumb);
        mainTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainTitle);
        mainTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainTime);
        videos = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.videos);

    }

    private class ParseVideoDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        int count = 0;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            URL jsonURL;
            URLConnection jc;
            links = new ArrayList<String>();
            try {
                jsonURL = new URL("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/" +
                    YOUR PLAYLIST ID +  
                    "?v=2&alt=jsonc");
                 jc = jsonURL.openConnection(); 
                 InputStream is = jc.getInputStream(); 
                 String jsonTxt = IOUtils.toString(is); 
                 JSONObject jj = new JSONObject(jsonTxt); 
                 JSONObject jdata = jj.getJSONObject("data"); 
                 JSONArray aitems = jdata.getJSONArray("items"); 
                 for (int i=0;i<aitems.length();i++) {
                     JSONObject item = aitems.getJSONObject(i); 
                     JSONObject video = item.getJSONObject("video"); 
                     String title = video.getString("title");
                     JSONObject player = video.getJSONObject("player");
                     String link = player.getString("default");
                     String length = video.getString("duration");
                     JSONObject thumbnail = video.getJSONObject("thumbnail"); 
                     String thumbnailUrl = thumbnail.getString("hqDefault")
                     String[] deets = new String[4];
                     deets[0] = title;
                     deets[1] = thumbnailUrl;
                     deets[2] = length;
                     links.add(link);
                     publishProgress(deets);
                 }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }       
            return null;
        }       

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(final String... deets) {
            count++;
            if (count == 1) {
                MainActivity.setImageFromUrl(deets[1], mainThumb, Videos.this);
                mainTitle.setText(deets[0]);
                mainTime.setText(formatLength(deets[2]));
                mainThumb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(links.get(1)));
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)Videos.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View video = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.video, null);
                ImageView thumb = (ImageView) video.findViewById(R.id.thumb);
                TextView title = (TextView) video.findViewById(R.id.title);
                TextView time = (TextView) video.findViewById(R.id.time);
                MainActivity.setImageFromUrl(deets[1], thumb, Videos.this);
                title.setText(deets[0]);
                time.setText(formatLength(deets[2]));
                video.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
                videos.addView(video);
                video.setId(count-1);
                video.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(links.get(v.getId())));
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    private CharSequence formatLength(String secs) {
        int secsIn = Integer.parseInt(secs);
        int hours = secsIn / 3600,
                remainder = secsIn % 3600,
                minutes = remainder / 60,
                seconds = remainder % 60;

                return ((minutes < 10 ? "0" : "") + minutes
                + ":" + (seconds< 10 ? "0" : "") + seconds );
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        for (int i=0;i<videos.getChildCount();i++) {
            View v = videos.getChildAt(i);
            if (v instanceof ImageView) {
                ImageView iv = (ImageView) v;           
                ((BitmapDrawable)iv.getDrawable()).getBitmap().recycle();   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

video.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/thumb"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:scaleType="fitStart" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/thumb"
            android:layout_below="@+id/thumb"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/time"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/thumb"
            android:layout_below="@+id/thumb"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />              


</RelativeLayout>
```

videos.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >    

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mainThumb"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mainTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/mainThumb"
            android:layout_below="@+id/mainThumb"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/mainTime"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mainTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/mainThumb"
            android:layout_below="@+id/mainThumb"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />              
    </RelativeLayout>

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/videos"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

    </HorizontalScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Any idea on how to do the same with XML, I need the XML URL